# Parsing string from a CSV file to an integer

Tags: java, parsing, csv

I have a CSV file which displays a name followed by 3 integers as shown below.

```
"John","12","37","1000"
```

I have the 3 number `values` indexed as `values[1]`, `values[2]` and `values[3]`.

I am trying to parse the strings from the CSV file by using the following:

```
int wins = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
int losses = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);
int money = Integer.parseInt(values[3]);
```

My problem is that the values in the CSV file already are surrounded by `" "`, so when I try to parse the string it is trying to parse `""12""`, `""37""` and `""1000""`.

Is there any way in which I could ignore the `" "` in the CSV file without deleting them manually in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the substring between the quotes

```
values[1].substring(1, values[1].length() - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `str.replace("\"","")` to replace all the **"** in the string.

Comment: My mistake it should be replace!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.substring(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method.